# Recursive PHP function writing to external array

Tags: php, recursion, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Two questions here really; why is this happening? And what can be done about it?

Sorry the question's so long but most of it is just `print_r` output!

Basically, I start with a flat array of tags (`$tags`) each with an `id` (array index), `name` and `parent_id`. I then recursively iterate over `$tags` and nest all child tags within their parent. (see below)

It works! (see below for output). But the problem I'm having is that my flat array of tags is being written to from within the function that does the nesting/recursion. (see below)

Flat array of tags:

```
Array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => instruments
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => strings
            [parent_id] => 1
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => violin
            [parent_id] => 2
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => cello
            [parent_id] => 2
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => woodwind
            [parent_id] => 1
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => flute
            [parent_id] => 5
        )
)
```

This is the recursively called function to nest the child tags. The problem is inside the `if`: I assign `$tag` to `$tree[$i]` and then add the `children` property to it. This results in the `children` property being added to `$tag`. This is what I want to stop happening.

```
public function tags_to_tree($tags, $parent_id = 0)
{
    $tree = array();
    foreach($tags as $i => $tag)
    {
        // add this tag node and all children (depth-first recursive)
        if(intval($parent_id) === intval($tag->parent_id))
        {
            $tree[$i] = $tag;
            $tree[$i]->children = $this->tags_to_tree($tags, $i);
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Nested tags output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => instruments
            [parent_id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => strings
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [3] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => violin
                                            [parent_id] => 2
                                        )

                                    [4] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => cello
                                            [parent_id] => 2
                                        )
                                )
                        )

                    [5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => woodwind
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [6] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => flute
                                            [parent_id] => 5
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

What can I do differently when adding the `children` property to `$tree[$i]`, or when assigning `$tag` to `$tree[$i]` to stop this from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flat array is an array of objects (references), even though you are putting the objects into a new array, it is still the same object you are moving around.

If you don't want to be editing the same reference, have a look at [Object Cloning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

i.e. Use:

```
$tree[$i] = clone $tag;
```

Comment: amazing! such a long question for such a simple answer, thank you very much. tested and working :)